# JavaScript object that saves/loads its state

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I'd like to create a Javascript object that can save and load its state (to local storage).

This is the basic pattern I'm using:

```
var obj = function () {

    // private members
    //

    return {

        // public members

        load: function () {
            this.state = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('obj'));

            if (this.state === null) {
                this.state = {
                    name: 'foo'
                };
            }
        },

        save: function () {
            localStorage.setItem('obj', JSON.stringify(this.state));
        }
    };
}();

// load state
obj.load();
console.log(obj.state.name);

// save state
obj.state.name = 'bar';
obj.save();
```

But there's one thing that annoys me about this pattern: I have to access the object's persistent properties through the 'state' property.

How can I rewrite this so I can use the object in a more natural way, like:

```
// load state
obj.load();
console.log(obj.name);

// save state
obj.name = 'bar';
obj.save();
```

This is a very simple 'state', but the solution has to work for a complex state object with nested objects, arrays etc., so simply adding a 'name' property to my object is not what I'm after.

Comment: Use an extend function: http://jsfiddle.net/m6ug2/.

Comment: This looks promising, why don't you post that as an answer so you can get credit?

Comment: @pimvdb would you mind promoting this to an answer?

Comment: Are you using jquery or is using jquery an option?  If so, it's a good suggestion.  It's a shortcut of doing what my answer suggests.

Comment: Yes my solution uses jQuery, but would be interested to see a solution not using jQuery too.

Comment: @saille then see my answer below.  And see Jan's comment.  You could make my answer 'smarter' by checking if x is a function in the loop and, if so, skip it.  If it's not the answer you're looking for I won't bother editing it to include this scenario.

Comment: It's basically @Eli's answer, but with jQuery. Give him credit :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care which properties get loaded/saved then you can simply copy all from state into self.  For example, after reading into `var state` (instead of `this.state` since you don't want `state` to be a part of `this` anymore): `for(x in state) this[x] = state[x];`

similarly, you'd save out: `var state = {}; for(x in this) state[x] = this[x]`

However, if you want to have a pre-defined list, then I'd recommend: `var fields = ['name', 'zip', 'age'];`

And then use `for(x in fields) this[x] = state[x]` to load and `for(x in fields) state[x] = this[x];` to save.

Sorry it's a bit pieced together, but I hope you can follow what I mean :)

EDIT: Added full example per OPs request.

An example of a full solution using this technique is as follows:

```
var obj = function () {

    // private members
    //

    return {

        // public members

        load: function () {
            var state = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('obj'));

            if(state == null) state = { name: 'foo' };

            for(x in state) this[x] = state[x];
        },

        save: function ()
        {
            var state = {};

            // check if it's a function.  This version taken from underscorejs
            var isFunction = function(obj) {
                return !!(obj && obj.constructor && obj.call && obj.apply);
            };

            for(x in this)
            {
               if(isFunction(this[x])) continue; // skip functions

               state[x] = this[x];
            }

            localStorage.setItem('obj', JSON.stringify(state));
        }
    };
};
```

Comment: Note you don't want to move all properties to the serialized state. Namely, you don't want to serialize functions.

Comment: Seems a bit costly copying all the data? Hoping for something more elegant.

Comment: `$.extend` is doing the same thing.  Without first running it and checking performance I think it's a bit too quick to jump to conclusions about performance.

Comment: +1 for a solution, but you have to admit it lacks elegance - its brute force.

Comment: You mentioned javascript.  If you are using a jquery I prefer `$.extend` but under the hood it is still brute force.  It is brute force because that's your only option.  I think what you want is something like `this = JSON.parse(...)` but you can't do that.  As far as I know this type of solution is your only possible solution.

Comment: If you show a complete code sample with functions excluded I'll mark as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can also accomplish a direct save when a property changes, 
by using ES5 getters/setters or by using [Watch.js](https://github.com/melanke/Watch.JS)

**Watch.js example:**

```
var obj = (function () {
    // private members
    //
    var self = {
        // Some properties
        name: '',
        otherName: '',            
        // Try to load state or use "foo state"
        state: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('obj')) || {
                    name: 'foo'
        },            
        save: function () {
            localStorage.setItem('obj', JSON.stringify(this.state));
        }
    };
    // Watch the object and save it to local storage, when a property changes
    // (Of course, you don't need to call the save method here...)
    watch(self, function(property, value) {        
        console.log('saving state!');
        self.state[property] = value;            
        self.save();
    });

    return self;
}());

// Update some properties and see that it is saved to local storage.
obj.name = "Some name";
obj.otherName = "Some other name";    
console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('obj')));
```

​
Example on [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XEsQd/).

Answer (score 0):

You could make the `state` internal and surface getters and setters:

```
var obj = function () {
    // private members
    var state = {};

    return {
        // public members
        load: function () {
            var loadedState = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('obj'));

            if (loadedState === null) {
                state = {
                    name: 'foo'
                };
            } else {
                state = loadedState;
            }
        },
        save: function () {
            localStorage.setItem('obj', JSON.stringify(state));
        },
        getState: function (key) {
            return state[key];
        },
        setState: function (key, value) {
            state[key] = value;
        }
    };
};
```

Comment: But then I would have to access state in much the same way, except using your getState() function instead of my state property, so that doesn't help much.

Comment: @saille if you want the state to be write-only, then remove the `getState` function.

Comment: I don't want write only, I want to access my objects properties like: obj.name, NOT obj.getState().name

Comment: Point of clarification.  His solution would have you do `obj.getState('name')` which still falls short of what you want to do but I wanted to at least point out the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Using [jQuery's extend()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/):

```
var obj = (function () {
    return {
        load: function () {
            var stored = localStorage.getItem("obj");
            var state = stored ? JSON.parse(stored) : {
                name: 'foo'
            };
            $.extend(this, state);
        },

        save: function () {
            localStorage.setItem("obj", JSON.stringify(this));
        }
    };
})();

// load state
obj.load();
console.log(obj);

// save state
obj.name = 'bar';
obj.save();
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m6ug2/)

All credit to pimvdb.